# How to add text box template to auto generate grid view (ASP.NET) and copy few columns from grid view & save them to another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is my front end for grid view

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"> //This is auto generated grid view..

            <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
        <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="remarks" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox> //This is the text box
 which i need to copy with some columns and save it in another table in sql server
 and i need to put this column as last column but it is coming as first
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

This is back end. My main doubt is to how to copy the columns with out column numbers from a auto generated grid

```
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind(); //how can i solve this? How to set the column in the last in auto generate columns
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        //Message
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: use datatable to place column at last position or anywhere you want.

Comment: actually i am new to this can you tell me briefly

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-create-DataTable-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx